# mac pre-bundled python and newly-installed one

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I'm trying to install python and its library in bash, using brew and pip.

When I type command

```
pip list
```

it seems that numpy(1.8.0rc1), matplotlib(1.3.1), scipy(0.13.0b1) are all installed. However, when I type ipython command and enter the interactive python interface,

```
import numpy
```

works fine, but

```
import matplotlib
import scipy
```

run into error saying that "ModuleNotFoundError".

I think it is because OS has its own pre-bundled python and pip list command shows what libraries are installed for the pre-bundled one. But ipython command enters into the newly-installed python where those two libraries are not installed.

So could any one talk about the two pythons, and how could I install the library to the correct position and enter the proper python.

I've tried brew, reinstall, pip, sudo and they didn't work quite well.
BTW, when type print(sys.path) in ipython, it gives

```
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/bin', '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/vendor/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6', '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/numpy/1.13.3/libexec/nose/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/ipython/6.2.1/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/bazinga/.ipython']
```

Comment: Try upgrading `pip` by using `pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is that you now have two Python installations, one being the system one:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

and the other one installed via Homebrew ("brewed" Python):

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.3
```

When you issue `pip list`, you are listing packages installed for the system Python. You can check what Python installation does `pip` belong by issuing `pip -V`. The package manager for the brewed Python is `pip3`, check this: `pip3 -V`. All the commands valid for `pip` will also work with `pip3`, for example list packages by issuing `pip3 list` etc.

The `ipython` Installation uses the brewed Python, so in order to install packages so be accessible by `ipython`, use `pip3`:

```
$ pip3 install --user numpy matplotlib scipy
```